# How netbeans installation file (bash file) contains Java code?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netbeans

I wonder, how a bash file can contain a Java code that is responsible about the installation of netbeans IDE which is as known is a Java based program?
this is the case of netbeans:

```
$ file netbeans-6.8-ml-java-linux.sh 
netbeans-6.8-ml-java-linux.sh: POSIX shell script text executable
$ more netbeans-6.8-ml-java-linux.sh
#!/bin/sh
# 
# DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.
# 
# Copyright 1997-2007 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
```

How this can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a [shar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) file (shell archive).